# Member function parameter type is a nested class

Tags: c++, class

```
class Solution {
public:
    void func(test t)
    {

    }
    class test
    {

    };  
    
};
```

Compiling this gives the error

```
error: unknown type name 'test'
    void func(test t)
```

I added a scope to the type test

```
class Solution {
public:
    void func(Solution::test t)
    {

    }
    class test
    {

    };  
    
};
```

But this gives

```
test.cpp:47:25: error: no type named 'test' in 'Solution'
    void func(Solution::test t)
```

I presume this is because the function `test` does not know about `class test` because it is declared below it. So I added a declaration above `test`

```
class Solution {
public:
    class test;
    void func(Solution::test t)
    {

    }
    class test
    {

    };  
    
};
```

Now this code compiles (it also compiles if I remove the `Solution::` scope), but I have 2 questions.

(1) If `func` called some other member function that was defined below it, it works, but why does it complain about not knowing the class `test` in this case?

(2) Is there any point in adding the `Solution::` in this situation?

Comment: @RetiredNinja "Compilers read from the top down" -- but why does this not apply to a situation where, e.g., `func()` calls another function that's defined below it?

Comment: Declarations (including prototypes of in-class function definitions) are processed first, from the top down. Function bodies are only processed after the declarations are known.

Answer (score 5):

What you are dealing with here is called the [*complete-class context* of a class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem.general-7) which is

> A complete-class context of a class (template) is a
>
> - function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument ([dcl.fct.default]),
> - default template argument ([temp.param]),
> - noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class or class template.

The parameters of a member function are not part of this, so they must be types that have already been defined, which it is not in this case.  It works once you add `class test;` first, because now the type is declared and that is all that is required for a function declaration.

So, the solution is to define `test` first, or forward declare it like you do in your last example.